# Is it possible to install Ubuntu 18.04 on Mac M1?

Tags: 18.04

I tried several ways to install Ubunto on M1, I need the 18.04 version using VMware and Virtual Box, with no success.
Is it possible? if yes - how? there is some specific guide for it?

Comment: You are aware that Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, which was released in 2018-April (thus the 18.04), has five years of *standard* support thus reaches the EOSS in 2023-April (ie. next month!)...   Why install a product that only has ~one month of *standard* support remaining?

Comment: You are right, but our company is using application that runs on 18.04 yet